# How to pass body in Retrofit using Kotlin Android?

Tags: android, api, kotlin, retrofit

I am trying to fetch data from a local server API using Retrofit Kotlin Android. The server has a body

`{ "uid":1 }`

How can I pass this uid through retrofit to the API call?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the sample code to send objects in the request in the body.

```
public interface TaskService {  
    @POST("/tasks")
    Call<Task> createTask(@Body Task task);
}
```

where Task is as follows:

```
public class Task {  
    private long uid;

    public Task(long uid) {
        this. uid = uid;
    }
}
```

and wherever u r calling call like this.

```
Task task = new Task(1);  
Call<Task> call = taskService.createTask(task);  
call.enqueue(new Callback<Task>() {
  //do something
});
```